# Using Process Builder with an Opportunity in order to update Contact and Account Last Modified

Tags: workflow, process-builder

By chance, I figured out how to update the System Last Modified date on a Contact when an Opportunity with that contact is updated.  I used the object Deal, with Opportunity - LastModifiedDate- Is changed.  My Action was to update the field called Note.

I do not see the text string in the Note of the contact updated, but it does update the contact's system last active.

QUESTION:
What object and actions do I use to update the Account name's system last active date when the Opportunity is updated.

End goal: internal corporate create Deals based upon a contact for all activity. We wish to update the Contact last active and the Account last active any time the deal is modified.  Final goal- create report on Accounts to show last system activity dates.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom date field on the account object and had contacts and opportunities update this date on the account field, the account would then update all child records.